# Using statement in context of streams and WebClients

Tags: c#

Mostly a question on which approach would be better *and* when utilizing the `using` keyword, would it still be neccesary to close streams programatically. If an object implements `IDisposable` should `using` always be used?

Link to my full answer using this sample: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563302/calling-and-get-result-text-from-service/9564067#9564067)

Option 1:

```
WebClient webClient;
webClient = new WebClient();
string json = webClient.DownloadString(@"urlToTheJsonResponse");

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GISData));
stream.Position = 0;
GISData data = (GISData)ser.ReadObject(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Option 2:

```
WebClient webClient;
MemoryStream stream;
string json;
GISData data;

using (webClient = new WebClient())
{
    json = webClient.DownloadString(@"urlToTheJsonResponse");
}

using (stream = new MemoryStream((Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GISData));
    data = (GISData)ser.ReadObject(stream);
    stream.Close();
}

using (webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(data.href, "C:/" + data.href.Substring(data.href.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you should always either call `Dispose()` explicitly or use a `using` block. This applies especially for streams and related types (like `StreamWriter`), where not disposing can have very visible bad consequences (e.g. the end of the text won't be written to the file).

But there are some types for which calling `Dispose()` doesn't actually do anything useful. And `WebClient` and `MemoryStream` are among them. They are `IDisposable` primarily because they inherit that interface from their base class (`Component` and `Stream`, respectively). So, I think your Option 1 is fine.

If you are unsure whether you should dispose objects of some type or whether it's one of the few types where not disposing is safe, err on the side of caution and dispose it.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is over two years later, but I thought I should point out a redundancy in the code in the OP. I see this:

```
using (stream = new MemoryStream((Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))) {
  DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GISData));
  data = (GISData)ser.ReadObject(stream);
  stream.Close();
}
```

Notice that `stream.Close();` at the end of the block - which, of course, is unnecessary since `stream` is the object of the `using`.

(I would have just used comment under the OP, but I just signed up to this particular branch of stackexchange and don't have the rep requirement.)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review SE. Good catch on the `stream.Close()`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should, classes which implement IDisposable are basically stating that they internally have used managed or unmanaged resources which require explicit tidy up outside of the remit of the garbage collector. The using statement is simply a compiler short cut to a try/finally block which ensures that the dispose method is called even if the code inside the using block throws an exception.

```
using (webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(data.href, "C:/" + data.href.Substring(data.href.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
}
```

becomes

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
try
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(data.href, "C:/" + data.href.Substring(data.href.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
}
finally
{
    if (webClient != null)
    {
        webClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Although the garbage collector will call the Finalize() method on any IDisposable instance that implements one, that won't happen until the object is available for garbage collection and therefore the tidy up won't happen until some point in the future.

Most classes with a finalizer will call the dispose method but usually only tidy up unmanaged resources when called from the finalizer, therefore it is still recommended to call dispose yourself as soon as you are finished with an object to ensure that you don't hold on to other resources longer than necessary.

Comment: This is completely wrong. The GC **never** calls `Dispose()`. But it does call the finalizer, which usually does the same cleanup of unmanaged resources as `Dispose()`.

Comment: @svick - I don't think you understand the meaning of the word  "completely." For example, finding a pedantic error among a multi-faceted answer that is otherwise correct is not "completely wrong." I'm only saying something because your comment may mislead some people with regards to the quality of the question.

Comment: @SeanH, well, I don't think that's a pedantic error. I think it's quite important and if you believe what Trevor wrote, it might bite you big time.

Comment: @svick is correct, I meant to say Finalize not Dispose in that last paragraph I'll update the answer to correct it.

Comment: @TrevorPilley, it's still not correct. Your current text makes it sound like `Finalize()` has something to do with `IDisposable`. Sure, when you have `Finalize()` you almost always implement `IDisposable` too, but it's not technically necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, always. Unless it's a class-level variable in which your type should then implement `IDisposable` and dispose of them in its `Dispose()` method.

So, option 2.

Comment: Well, except HttpClient. Because a rule wouldn't be a rule without an exception somewhere: http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/